# Why is my underline showing up misaligned?

Tags: html, underline

[screenshot of links with a hover underline; all the links look like they're slightly running over to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKi4E.png)

My code is (sorry if messy / not the best form. I've pieced together HTML / CSS I've taught myself over the years):

```
<nav class="index-navigation" role="navigation">
  
<p class="customtitle" style="padding:-50px; margin-top:-20px; padding-bottom:20px;">EXPLORE PROJECTS</p>
<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" data-ajax-loader="ajax-loader-binded" href="/"><span class="navlink">All</span></a>
  
<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" href="/colour-well/">“<span class="navlink">TO COLOUR WELL</span>”</a>

<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" href=“/bolts/" data-ajax-loader="ajax-loader-binded"><span class="navlink" >BOLTS</span></a>

<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" data-ajax-loader="ajax-loader-binded" href=“/mito/“><span class="navlink" style="border-bottom:1px solid black">MITO</span></a>

<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" data-ajax-loader="ajax-loader-binded" href=“/fertilityiq/“><span class="navlink">FertilityIQ</span></a>
 
<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" data-ajax-loader="ajax-loader-binded" href=“/rise/“><span class="navlink">Rise</span></a>

<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" data-ajax-loader="ajax-loader-binded" href="/spark/"><span class="navlink">Spark</span></a>
  
<a class="index-nav-link index-all-link" data-ajax-loader="ajax-loader-binded" href="/oily/"><span class="navlink">OILY</span></a>


</nav>
```

Comment: Perhaps the underline for the font has different padding. Can we test this with a different font?

Comment: That doesn't look like the HTML for the image you show. For example your HTML has a bottom border for MITO but not for Spark, but the image shows a bottom border on both. Also, do you have any other CSS you are including with this HTML? Your bottom border might also be fighting with whatever your other classes are doing.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a code snippet including the css file containing the classes applied to the HTML.